# How do I detect if device is charging from background

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have searched thick and thin through the Developer notes for android and am unable to find out how to perform a specific action when a device is plugged in, and perform another action when unplugged.

I have attempted to set a Broadcast Receiver like below however it will not run:

```
    <receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I understand that from API 26 and up, you can no longer receive some broadcasts registered in the manifest, and must register them dynamically.

I need to have this run in the background but can't figure out how? This article updated in 2019 (after api 26) implies that I should be able to do it.

> The charging status can change as easily as a device can be plugged in, so it's important to monitor the charging state for changes and alter your refresh rate accordingly.
>
> The BatteryManager broadcasts an action whenever the device is connected or disconnected from power. It's important to receive these events **even while your app isn't running particularly as these events should impact how often you start your app in order to initiate a background update so you should register a BroadcastReceiver in your manifest to listen for both events by defining the ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED and ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED within an intent filter.**

My end goal is to call the broadcast receiver whenever device is plugged in or unplugged.

How would I go about implementing this?

Comment: you need to register this receiver from code

Comment: But that wouldn't allow me to get the intent from background. It would only get the intent of activity is alive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this is by having a service run in the background so that you can receive the broadcast from android without the user using the app.

Start by registering a service in your manifest file.

```
<Service android:name=".serviceName"/>
```

Now create your class with the same name as registered in the manifest above, this class must extend Service.

```
    public class BackgroundService extends Service {
        private static final int NOTIF_ID = 1;
        private static final String NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID = "AppNameBackgroundService";

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

            //Add broadcast receiver for plugging in and out here
            ChargeDetection chargeDetector = new ChargeDetection(); //This is the name of the class at the bottom of this code.

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
            this.registerReceiver(chargeDetector, filter);

            startForeground();

            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }

        private void startForeground() {
            createNotificationChannel();
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    notificationIntent, 0);

            startForeground(NOTIF_ID, new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,
                    NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID) // don't forget create a notification channel first
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.final_icon)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText("Background service is running")
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .build());
        }

        private void createNotificationChannel() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                        NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID,
                        "Foreground Service Channel",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
                );
                NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
                manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
            }
        }
    }

    class ChargeDetection extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //Now check if user is charging here. This will only run when device is either plugged in or unplugged.
        }
    }   
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to register this receiver from code

You could run a WorkManager to run once every 15 minutes (the minimum is once every 15 minutes)
register the receiver, check if it's charging
unregister the receiver

Comment: My problem is that the app needs to turn on Do Not Disturb when charging, tasker seems to be able to do this effectively and I am not sure how they manage this post api 26.

The article also implies that you can do it from the background, is this not true ?

Comment: tasker is defined as a system app ?

Comment: Simply you can set constraints for WorkManager: `setRequiresCharging(true)`. It runs when device is charging.